# ng-bootstrap typeahead format on all object properties

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm working on an angular 6 proj and I'm using ng-bootstrap typeahead for searching through this object:

```
const options: SelectItem[] = [
{ name: 'home', id: 1 },
{ name: 'dashboard', id: 2 },
{ name: 'panel', id: 3 } ];
```

now I just can search by name:

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        map(term => term === '' ? []
            : options.filter(v => v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
    )
formatter = (result: string) => result.toUpperCase();
```

but I wanna search both on id and name in my search field ...
any body can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the function search to include the new condition

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        map(term => term === '' ? []
            : options.filter(v => 
               v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase())>-1 ||
               v.id==+term
            ).slice(0, 10))
    )
```

See that, as id is a number, so you need convert term to number (the +term)

a simple example can be see in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwjw9q?file=app/typeahead-template.ts)